# Track stereo footage

Tags: tracking

I have 2 footages. One for the left eye, and one for the right eye.

Is there any way to track the cameras from these footages and get the stereo camera from it? Or get 2 separate cameras from it, but at the same position if it was stereo camera?

I can track cameras separately, but I get separate solutions.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49464/2843

Answer (score 1):

I think you should track for one eye and then parent another camera to the first and adjust the distances between the two and also the rotation until it looks right.